# unable to get the accurate geo-location on Nexus 4 and 10

Tags: geolocation, gps, wifi, geocoding, locationmanager

How to get the most accurate geo-location on an android device, I tried following code snippet But on Nexus 4 and 10, it doesn't work even after the gps is turned on :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            String locationProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
            if (locationProvider != null) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "locationProvider is not null");
                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

                if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                    AppConstants.lat = latLon[0] = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                    AppConstants.lon = latLon[1] = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
                    retryGenerating = false;
                    //Log.d(TAG, "lastKnownLocation, lat = " + AppConstants.lat + ", lon = " + AppConstants.lon);

                }
}
```

Comment: What so you mean, with it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate location you get by explicitly setting the `LocationProvider` to GPS Provider. Expect usually  3-6m accuracy, up to 30m in urban canyons.

You need to to be outside and have free view to sky.
Expect a delay of 20-40 s for the first valid location after going outside.